# Ubuntu randomly rebooting

Tags: kernel, reboot

For a while my computer has been rebooting randonmly, it used to be only a couple times a week, but now is happening around 4-5 times a day.

I've tried checking the error logs and there is nothing other than "-- Reboot --".

```
Sep 16 10:39:01 {username} audit[788]: USER_AVC pid=788 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal" bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.login1" exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Sep 16 10:39:01 {username} audit: AUDIT1420 subj_apparmor=unconfined
Sep 16 10:39:01 {username} kernal: audit: type=1107 audit(1662133321.239:1531): pid=788 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal" bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Sep 16 10:39:01 {username} kernal: audit: type=1420 audit(1662133321.239:1532): subj_apparmor=unconfined
Sep 16 10:39:01 {username} CRON[43528]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
-- Reboot --
```

System specs:
Memory: 23.4 GiB (24GB worth of sticks),
Processor: Intel Core i5-3470 @ 3.20GHz x4,
Graphics: NV126,
Disk Capacity: 1.5TB,
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS,
OS Type: 64-bit,
GNOME version: 3.36.8,
Windowing System: X11.

EDIT:
It has just happened again:

```
Sep 16 11:00:31 {username} dbus-daemon[1883]: [session uid=1000 pid=1883] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.FileManager1' requested by ':1.37' (uid=1000 pid=2099 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Sep 16 11:00:31 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Sep 16 11:00:31 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Sep 16 11:00:31 {username} dbus-daemon[1883]: [session uid=1000 pid=1883] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.37' (uid=1000 pid=2099 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Sep 16 11:00:31 {username} dbus-daemon[1883]: [session uid=1000 pid=1883] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Sep 16 11:00:31 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Sep 16 11:00:31 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Sep 16 11:00:31 {username} dbus-daemon[1883]: [session uid=1000 pid=1883] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.FileManager1'
Sep 16 11:00:31 {username} org.gnome.Nautilus[8882]: Failed to register: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Sep 16 11:00:31 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: Received property WindowId with type u does not match expected type i in the expected interface
Sep 16 11:00:32 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Sep 16 11:00:32 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Sep 16 11:00:32 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Sep 16 11:00:32 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Sep 16 11:00:32 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Sep 16 11:00:32 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Sep 16 11:00:32 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Sep 16 11:00:32 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Sep 16 11:00:32 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Sep 16 11:00:32 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Sep 16 11:00:32 {username} gnome-shell[2099]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Sep 16 11:00:53 {username} kernel: [ 2827.447448] audit: type=1326 audit(1663322453.896:138): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=? pid=4288 comm="slack" exe="/snap/slack/65/usr/lib/slack/slack" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=92 compat=0 ip=0x7fc2fad833b7 code=0x50000
Sep 16 11:01:01 {username} systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Sep 16 11:02:07 {username} systemd-modules-load[274]: Inserted module 'lp'
Sep 16 11:02:07 {username} systemd-modules-load[274]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Sep 16 11:02:07 {username} systemd-modules-load[274]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Sep 16 11:02:07 {username} systemd-modules-load[274]: Inserted module 'msr'
Sep 16 11:02:07 {username} systemd-modules-load[274]: Inserted module 'ipmi_devintf'
Sep 16 11:02:07 {username} systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Modules.
Sep 16 11:02:07 {username} systemd[1]: Finished udev Coldplug all Devices.
Sep 16 11:02:07 {username} systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for bare, revision 5.
Sep 16 11:02:07 {username} systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for chromium-ffmpeg, revision 30.
Sep 16 11:02:07 {username} systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for core18, revision 2560.
Sep 16 11:02:07 {username} systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for core18, revision 2566.
Sep 16 11:02:07 {username} systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revision 72.
Sep 16 11:02:07 {username} systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
Sep 16 11:02:07 {username} kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x21, date = 2019-02-13
Sep 16 11:02:07 {username} kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.15.0-46-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-007) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 19:15:44 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.15.0-46.49~20.04.1-generic 5.15.39)
```

EDIT: it has just happened again. 5 mins before the crash was requested, here is 10 minutes:Here is 5 mins before the crash as requested:

```
Sep 16 11:40:29 {username} kernel: [ 2309.907198] audit: type=1326 audit(1663324829.837:101): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=? pid=3867 comm="slack" exe="/snap/slack/65/usr/lib/slack/slack" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=92 compat=0 ip=0x7f06c5ba43b7 code=0x50000
Sep 16 11:47:52 {username} kernel: [ 2752.772447] perf: interrupt took too long (2506 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
Sep 16 11:56:14 {username} gnome-shell[1868]: Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.#012This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
Sep 16 11:56:14 {username} gnome-shell[1868]: ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10558: The clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.
Sep 16 11:56:28 {username} /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1729]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-7ms), your system is too slow
Sep 16 11:58:08 {username} systemd[1]: Starting Ubuntu Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs...
Sep 16 11:58:08 {username} systemd[1]: ua-timer.service: Succeeded.
Sep 16 11:58:08 {username} systemd[1]: Finished Ubuntu Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs.
Sep 16 12:00:34 {username} systemd-modules-load[275]: Inserted module 'lp'
Sep 16 12:00:34 {username} systemd-modules-load[275]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Sep 16 12:00:34 {username} kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x21, date = 2019-02-13
Sep 16 12:00:34 {username} systemd-modules-load[275]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Sep 16 12:00:34 {username} systemd-modules-load[275]: Inserted module 'msr'
Sep 16 12:00:34 {username} kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.15.0-46-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-007) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 19:15:44 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.15.0-46.49~20.04.1-generic 5.15.39)
Sep 16 12:00:34 {username} kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic root=UUID=9960433c-78e3-46f1-a51b-e3d7e1265b21 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

Comment: Which type of computer? Is it getting too hot? Random reboots normally points towards hardware error or failsafes (like rebooting if system gets too hot). Some temperature readings would be a help. Also note that some (if not most) laptops are pasted *really poorly*, so if it's a laptop I would suggest repasting your CPU and graphics chip - but this is beyond the scope of this site. Tips on repasting would be suitable on [su].

Comment: Hi @ArturMeinild I've checked all the temps and CPU isn't getting above 55C.

Comment: I think you should provide the complete syslog entries for 5 minutes before a reboot - just to be sure.

Comment: @ArturMeinild it has just happened again, I have updated my post witht he last 10 minutes of logs as there wasn't many.

Comment: The lack of logged errors in the output strongly points to a hardware fault.

Comment: Your log suggests this is a VM is that correct?

Comment: @David, no, this is a regular installation of ubuntu 20